# How do I prove that no such T-invariant subspace exists?

Tags: matrices, direct-sum, invariant-subspace

Let $T : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ be the linear application have for matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
   2 \ 0 \ 0 \\
   1 \ 2 \ 0 \\
   0 \ 0 \ 3 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$

Let's say $W = \ker(T-2Id)$. How do I prove that no $T$-invariant $U$ subspace exists so that $\mathbb R^3 = W \oplus U$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ the canonical basis and $S=T - 2 Id$. We have $\ker S = \mathbb R e_2 = W$.

Suppose that $U$ is a linear subspace $U \subseteq \mathbb R^3$ with $\mathbb R e_2 \oplus U = \mathbb R^3$. We can write $e_3 = \lambda e_2 + u$ with $u \in U$. Then

$$e_3 = S.e_3 = \lambda S.e_2 + S.u= S.u.$$

As $U$ is supposed to be $T$-invariant, it is also $S$-invariant and $e_3$ belongs to $U$.

Let's now focus on $e_1$. We can write $e_1 = \alpha e_2 + a$ where $a \in U$. Applying $S$ on both sides of this equality we get

$$e_2 = S.e_1 = \alpha S.e_2 + S.a = S.a$$

and therefore $e_2 \in U$ in contradiction with $\mathbb R e_2 \oplus U = \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: kerS=Re2 Can you explain this line? I don't really understand what Re2 means.

Comment: The linear subspace generated by $e_2$.

Comment: Is that Sp{(0,1,0)}?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: Can you also explain:

e3=S.e3=λS.e2+S.u=S.u.

As U is supposed to be T-invariant, it is also S-invariant and e3 belongs to U.

Comment: Please make your own effort. I won't detail line by line.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thats realy not understandable. what are all those dots are? e3=S.e3=λS.e2+S.u=S.u.  I've never encountered such notaion.

Comment: This is a standard way to denote the application of an [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)?wprov=sfti1). $A.x$ means $A(x)$.